# WP_Query - Order results by meta value

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, order

I've checked around and haven't seen an answer which works as of yet. I have a WP_Query with the following arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'meta_key' => 'client_feedback_score',
    'orderby' => 'client_feedback_score',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I want to order the results by the custom post field `client_feedback_score`, lowest to highest. But this doesn't seem to work... can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT (SOLVED):**

Thanks to Milo's response, here's the working code for ordering by a numerical meta value:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'meta_key' => 'client_feedback_score',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`orderby` should be `meta_value_num`, or `meta_value`, not the name of the key. See [WP_Query orderby parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).

Comment: Worked a treat, cheers mate.

Comment: Thanks! You're my timesaver! Nowhere on WPCodex isn't mentioned about 'meta_value_num'.

Comment: Small note, if the `meta_key` does not exist for the post yet, the post will be ignored.

Comment: is `meta_value_num` a custom post meta that you can assign to post types? I need to be able to edit this value per post.

Comment: @RobBenz See [Custom Fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to learn about post meta.

Comment: thank you, I am familiar with custom post meta. I want to add a meta box to WC products, called `search_order` or something. so that when the search results are displayed: I can have the ability to control the order of their display. should I call the custom post meta that I am adding `meta_value_num`

Comment: or does `meta_value_num` just take the value of whatever 'meta_key' => 'search_order' is based on the post

Comment: @RobBenz `meta_value_num` is telling WP to order the results by a numeric meta value. It's not the key name.

Comment: how do i change `meta_value_num` so that a particular post will "rank" higher up the search results

Comment: @RobBenz You should probably start a new question on this topic. Step 1 Assign whatever value you want to your meta key, let's call it `my_meta_key`, for each post to generate whatever order you want. Step 2 You set `meta_key` in your query to `my_meta_key`. This tells WordPress to query for posts that have that key. Step 3 Set `orderby` in your query to `meta_value_num`. This tells WordPress to not only query posts with `my_meta_key`, but to also order numerically by that key. That query argument is the only place you will ever see or use `meta_value_num`.

Comment: @adamj is it any workaround this? I need sort all posts, regardless that meta_key exist for the post or not.

Comment: @unbreak the simple solution is to parse over all the posts and add the `meta_key` to them prior to running the order query

Answer (score 9):

if your meta value is not numeric for example if it is a date value; than you can add parameter `meta_type => DATE`.
Possible values are; `'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED'`.

Query with meta type will be like that:

```
$args = array(
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_type' => 'listing',
'meta_key' => 'client_feedback_score',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_type' => 'DATE',
'order' => 'DESC'
);
```