# Order posts according to user defined order for meta values?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, get-posts

I have set up some CPTs and storing a meta key/val for each of them. When I get those posts, I need to order them by the meta value, but, **the order of the meta values will be defined in an array by me**. The **default ordering for meta values is either alphabetical or numerical**, which I do not want.

I'll explain it in an example:

```
Post 1 =>
Meta key: Fruit
Meta value: Apple

Post 2 =>
Meta key: Fruit
Meta value: Melon

Post 3 =>
Meta key: Fruit
Meta value: Guava

Post 4 =>
Meta key: Fruit
Meta value: Banana
```

I get the order from an external source, and I want to get the posts in that order. Example: I get an order in an array: `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Guava', 'Melon']`. When I fetch the CPTs, I need to get them in this order. (Ignore the alphabetical ordering, I am just trying to give a general example).

How do I achieve it using a `meta_query` or any other solution?

If there is an existing thread, please redirect me to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP\_Query - Order results by meta value](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I think you have missed the question ;-)

Comment: I know that approach, but it orders the posts by the `alphabetical order` or `numerical order` of meta values assigned to them. I want to be able to define the order. @PieterGoosen Right, he did!

Comment: You will be, IMHO, better of sorting the results with `usort`. It is going to be very complicated, but doable

Comment: But that will be after I get the posts, right? Can you point me to an example?

Comment: Defining a custom order for MySQL queries needs the use of `ORDER BY FIELD()`, which you can introduce using [`posts_orderby` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby). But I'm not sure if it is better than select the posts and then order the results using PHP functions as @PieterGoosen suggests. You could study the two options.

Comment: I have done a lot of posts using `usort`, feel free to go through them. Unfortunately I do not have time to work on a concrete solution here

Comment: Rutwick, do you mean you will be passing an array of fruit types to query and you want the posts to be fetched in that order? So if you pass array **['Apple', 'Banana', 'Guava', 'Melon']** then are you expecting the query to give you all apple posts first then all banana posts then all guava posts and son on? Another question is that whether the meta value has fixed options? (I don't know how this last question would matter but just want to know).

Comment: @ItsMePN Yes, I want to be able to use an array for defining the sort order. There will be only one post per value. Meaning, one for Apple, one for Banana and so on. The meta values are going to be fixed. The problem is, I will be creating the posts first, and add the custom field. Later I will be receiving the order of posts by the meta values from another source. Custom taxonomies are already used!

Comment: @cybmeta Your solution looks neat, let me try it.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks! I will look into it as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the value of the meta field is a single value (not serialized), this filter could work:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby' );
function custom_posts_orderby( $orderby_statement ) {

    $custom_order = array( 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Guava', 'Melon' );

    $custom_order = "'" . implode ( "', '", $custom_order ) . "'";

    $orderby_statement = "FIELD( meta_value, " . $custom_order . " )";

    return $orderby_statement;

}
```

Note that this will affect to all queries, so you need to define the conditions to apply filter or not.

You can see more examples to build the `ORDER BY FIELD()` statemnet in [this post](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/).

Comment: Let me try this! I can apply the filter before the `get_posts` call and remove it immediately after.

Comment: See @birgire's answer, it follows the same approach but it is really better. It implements the filter in a way that allow you to specify the custom order in `meta__in` agument of WP_Query or get_posts, then this argument is checked in the filter, so you don't need to worry about any conditional to apply the filter or not. Just set the `meta__in` argument and you are ready to go.

Comment: Yes! I am looking at it!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Have edited the implode as it wasn't putting quotes around the strings which is needed inside the SQL

Answer (score 2):

*My proposed solution is already posted by @cybmeta (+1), but I add it anyway, since it deals with it in a general way ;-)*

In the same way the `WP_Query` parameters:

```
'post__in' => [1,2,3],
'orderby' => 'post__in'
```

give use the custom defined order:

```
ORDERBY FIELD( wp_posts.ID, 1, 2, 3 )
```

we can define our own meta ordering using:

```
'meta__in' => [ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana' ],
'orderby' => 'meta__in'
```

to get the following SQL part:

```
ORDERBY FIELD( wp_postmeta.meta_value, 'apple', 'orange', 'banana' )
```

First we define our own version of the `wp_parse_id_list()` helper function.

```
/**
* Note that this function is based on the core wp_parse_id_list() function.
* Clean up an array, comma- or space-separated list of string keys.
*
* @uses sanitize_key()
* @param array|string $list List of keys.
* @return array Sanitized array of keys.
*/
function wpse_parse_meta_list( $list )
{
    if ( ! is_array( $list ) )
        $list = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $list);

    return array_unique( array_map( 'sanitize_key', $list ) );
}
```

### Demo plugin

Then we construct the following demo plugin, to add a support for `'meta__in'` ordering, in  `WP_Query`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Support for order by meta__in in WP_Query
 */

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function ( $orderby, \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( $meta__in = $q->get( 'meta__in' ) )
    {
        if( is_array( $meta__in ) && ! empty( $meta__in ) )
        {
            global $wpdb;   

            // Transform the meta__in array into a comma separated strings of keys
            // Example [ 'apple', 'banana' ] --> "apple", "banana"
            $list = '"' . join( '","', wpse_parse_meta_list( $meta__in ) ) . '"';           

            // Override the orderby part with custom ordering:
            $orderby = " FIELD( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value, {$list} ) ";
        }
    }
    return $orderby;
}, 10, 2 );

/**
 * Note that this function is based on the core wp_parse_id_list() function.
 * Clean up an array, comma- or space-separated list of string keys.
 *
 * @uses sanitize_key()
 * @param array|string $list List of keys.
 * @return array Sanitized array of keys.
 */
function wpse_parse_meta_list( $list )
{
    if ( ! is_array( $list ) )
        $list = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $list);

    return array_unique( array_map( 'sanitize_key', $list ) );
}
```

where we've added the helper function into the plugin.

### Notes

We only use the `'meta__in'` parameter for ordering and not for extra `WHERE` restrictions, like we have with the `'post__in'` parameter. But that might be an interesting extension ;-)

Also note that `get_posts()`, that's just a `WP_Query` wrapper, has the following parameter set up by default:

```
'suppress_filters' => true
```

i.e. it doesn't accept the `posts_*` filters by default.

So if you can't use `WP_Query` or `get_posts()` with the `suppress_filters => false`, then you would need an alternative approach, e.g. suggested by @PieterGoosen.

Comment: I'm the `usort()` guy here, you are the funny extra parameters (which I prefer above mine) guy here, hahahaha. +1

Comment: hehehe, the more variations in solutions, the merrier ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: It makes the stack more useful.

Comment: Very nice and complete answer. +1

Comment: Looks pretty awesome! Trying it.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated, IMHO, with your best option for what you need is going to be `usort()` to sort the returned array of posts

Here is an untested theory

```
$sortorder = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Guava', 'Melon'];
$args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key'   => 'Fruit',
            'value' => $sortorder
        ]
    ],
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );

@usort( $q->posts, function( $a, $b ) use ( $sortorder  ) {
    // Get the meta values from the two posts to be compared
    $array_a = get_post_meta( $a->ID, 'Fruit', true );
    $array_b = get_post_meta( $b->ID, 'Fruit', true );

    // Reverse our $sortorder, key/value becomes value/key
    $flipped_order = array_flip( $sortorder );

    // Let start our sorting
    // If our meta values are the same order by date
    if ( $flipped_order[$array_a] != $flipped_order[$array_b] ) {
        return $flipped_order[$array_a] - $flipped_order[$array_b] // Swop around to reverse ordering
    } else {
        return $a->post_date < $b->post_date; // Change to > if you need oldest posts first
    }
});

// Run your loop normally
```

### EDIT

I have not brought in any safety to my code. You would want to make sure that `$sortorder` is a valid array, then you need to sanitize and validate the values before you use them to avoid malicious code.

You can do this for the main query aswell, the only thing is then that you would want to wrap the `usort()` function in the `the_posts` filter and then use `$posts` in place of `$q->posts`

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of @cybmeta here's another snippet of code that shows example of how you might sensibly decide when to this filter should activate. This assumes that you've specified an order by the meta_key on the query object somewhere, e.g. by hooking `parse_query`.

```
function custom_orderby_orders($orderby, $query) {

  if ($query->query['post_type'] == 'some_post_type' &&
      $query->query_vars['meta_key'] == 'meta_key_you_want_to_order') {
    
    $neworder = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

    $ordersql = "'" . implode("', '", $neworder) . "'";

    return "FIELD(meta_value, " . $ordersql . ")";

  } else { 

    return $orderby;

  }
}

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_orderby_orders', 10,2);
```