# Sort wordpress posts by facebook likes

Tags: order, sort, facebook

I found a theme that I really like: http://pluto.pinsupreme.com/masonry-compact-facebook As you can see every post has Facebook likes displayed in the exerpt. I would like to know if it would be possible to sort them by the amount of Likes they have? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can either sort them with jQuery on the front-end, or pull the like count into the back-end and store on the [post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). Then sort by [meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value) in your loop.

**FACEBOOK**

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://{URL}
```

Result

```
{
   "id": "http://{URL}",
   "shares": intgr/(number)
}
```

Other types of [share counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012357/facebook-twitter-linkedin-share-link-count).