# How to display sticky post always at the top (before regular post) in wordpress?

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, sticky-post

I am working on a wordpress code as shown below in which the **modified post displays at the top**.

```
$temp_args = [
    'post_type' => array('current-channel', 'post', 'current-episodes'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => array(
        'feat_yes' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'ASC',
        'modified' => 'DESC',
        'date' => 'DESC'),
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"no_articles_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE},
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $cat_today,
        ],
    ],

];
$q = new WP_Query($temp_args);
```

At this moment, order by is done in the following way:

```
'orderby' => array(
    'feat_yes' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'ASC',
    'modified' => 'DESC',
    'date' => 'DESC'),
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above so that **sticky posts are displayed at the top before the regular post**.

The order should be in a way that **sticky post should be always at the top** and then **all the regular post**

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add the `feat_yes` as a `meta_key`

```
$temp_args = [
    'post_type' => array('current-channel', 'post', 'current-episodes'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'feat_yes',
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', /* or 'meta_value' */
        'post_type' => 'ASC',
        'modified' => 'DESC',
        'date' => 'DESC'),
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"no_articles_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE},
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $cat_today,
        ],
    ],

];
$q = new WP_Query($temp_args);
```

Here's a few relevant links:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters
- [WP_Query - Order results by meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value)
- [Custom query with orderby meta_value of custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15477/custom-query-with-orderby-meta-value-of-custom-field)

Comment: Adding feat_yes as a meta_key would keep the sticky posts always at the top ?

Comment: Maybe, given that `feat_yes` isn't a core WordPress variable of any kind that I know of, I'm guessing it's post-meta, and a boolean, in which case yes, ordering by it would give priority to those posts with the value.

Comment: I added your code in my codebase. Now its not displaying any post, not a single one. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I don't have enough information about the problem to offer you a better solution. Good luck with it though!