# Display Specific Posts at Start of Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, pre-get-posts, sticky-post

I'm attempting to mimic 'sticky' functionality on a custom post type using a simple ACF true/false field. I'd like to use `pre_get_posts` to modify my query to first show my 'sticky' posts at the top and then loop through the rest, excluding the sticky ones.

I understand how to exclude posts by ID or by meta value from the query but am stuck on a good way to show the sticky ones first.

Q: what is a logical method for modifying the query using `pre_get_posts` to show four specific posts before 'the rest'?

Comment: alternate method: use a do while loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WP\_Query - Order results by meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value)

Comment: Thanks, @leymannx. Order by meta value could work actually with the single caveat that I don't believe I'd be able to limit that ordering to first X posts with the value. That may not be a deal breaker though.

Comment: 3 months later I am searching for the same.

Have you found a working answer?