# Order Element By Custom Field in Wordpress

Tags: wp-query, order, rating

I'm working on wordpress and I want to order my post by rating. I'm new with it, and I need some help. I tried many things, but seem it's not working :/

My Wordpress Custom field which contain the numerical value (rating) is : `geekmag_cmb2_general_review`

I have heard about WP Query but don't understand how it works/use it and where should I write the `WP_Query` :(

Sorry if it seam easy to you, but I really want to understand how to do and how it works, that is why i post here.

Here image about how i can filter right now [image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: [Order results by meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. If i select Meta Value, I have to specify something in Additional ?

Comment: Where do you want to sort your posts (blog page, list in sidebar, some specific page with a list of posts)? Is posts come from the main loop, or perhaps you are using the `get_posts()` function, or create a new `WP_Query` object?

Comment: In a Widget from my template. This widget select post and allow me to filter em by date, meta value, meta num value.. But i can't order by rating :(

Comment: I have custom field in my post, and i want to order them by the custom field "geekmag_cmb2_general_review"

Tried things but not working at all

Comment: Whether or not you can change the query depends on whether the creator of the widget uses filter hooks that would allow you to change the query parameters. I do not know the widget so I can not answer. Have you tried to paste the custom field name into `Additional`? Where does the "See query posts" link from the last print screen lead? Maybe there you'll find the information you need.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for fast answer ! Link goes to Wordpress Dock, but i finally did what i wanted ! Juste order by meta num value and in "Additionnal args" i add "meta_key=geekmag_cmb2_general_review" and it's working ! :)

I was looking for somthing harder but sometimes, simplest is better