# Sort wordpress custom posts based on meta value

Tags: wp-query, order, sort

I'm trying to sort the custom posts based on meta value as priority level1, level2 and level3. I have given a dropdown field in post meta as featured posts, standard posts and basic posts. I want to display them as featured posts on top, then standard posts and then basic posts. I tried with below code but it's not sorting the posts in the order.

Any guidance or advise much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
Array(
    'name'          => __( 'Listing Type Options', 'text-domain' ),
    'id'            => 'lising_type_options',
    'type'          => 'select',
    'child_of' => '',
    'options' => array(
        '' => 'Select Listing Type',
        '1' => 'Basic',
        '2' => 'Standard',
        '3' => 'Featured',
    ),
    'desc' => ''
),

if( isset( $lp_type ) && !empty( $lp_type ) ){
     if( $lp_type == '3' ){
          $lp_type = 'Featured';
     } elseif( $lp_type == '2' ){
          $lp_type = 'Standard';
     } elseif( $lp_type == '1' ){
          $lp_type = 'Basic';
     }
} else{
     $lp_type = '';
}
```

This is the query:

```
            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => $type,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => $postsonpage,
                    'paged'  => $paged,
                    'post__not_in' =>$ad_campaignsIDS,
                    'tax_query' => $TxQuery,
                    // 'meta_key'   => $MtKey,
                    // 'orderby' => $lporderby,
                    // 'order'   => $lporders,
                    'order'      => 'DESC',
                    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                                $MtKey,
                                array(
                                    'relation' => 'OR',
                                    array( 
                                        'key'     => 'lp_listingpro_options',
                                        'value'   => 'lising_type_options',
                                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'key'     => 'lp_listingpro_options',
                                        'value'   => 'lising_type_options',
                                        'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
                                    ),
                                ),
                        ),
                );
```

Comment: Check this [post - WP_Query - Order results by meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value) that you could set the proper args.

Comment: The `$MtKey` after `relation => 'OR'` is throwing me.... ...what is that and why is it there?  I don't see anything in your code that defines that variable and I also don't understand why it's dropped in the middle of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. Managed to find what the cause was. Its caused because of sticky feature, my posts was not sorted accordingly.
So, can anyone suggest me how do I remove saved sticky feature field from the database?

Any help would be much appreciated!